# why onConfigurationchanged is not called for android:configChanges="locale"?

Tags: android, android-manifest, local

I want to do something when change language occurs. So I put for activity in Manifest.xml in attribute andorid:configCahnges locale:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>           
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

but when I run my app and go to setting and change language the method onConfigurationchanged isn't call in MainAcitvity. Why? Docs for android says that it should. 
I develop for API 16.

I find out that if I put add to `android:configChanges` layoutDirection and set `android:minSdkVersion="17"` the method is called. (I run app on 4.2.2)

but now I couldn't refresh the text to new language.
I try to call:

```
 getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

in onConfigurationChanged but without success. :(

Comment: I think you are trying to change the language of the device and according to the changed language you want to also change the language of your application. Is that so ?

Comment: `android:configChanges` method is used to manage your activity against the events like orientation changed in device, SoftKeyboard is open etc.. To change the locale in your application you have to define its resources values in your application `res/values` folders for relevant language.

Comment: @Grishu I don't want to change language from application. I want to react for that (e.g. user changes the language)
I want to use standard mechanism of android for translation but I don't want onDestroy() when user change of language.

Comment: @GrIsHu now I read your comment again. And yes, I want.

Comment: The real question here should be, why do you want to handle yourself the activity recreation when `locale` is changed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"` in order for `onConfigurationChanged()` to be called.

Answer (score -1):

```
        android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
```

worked on 4.4

Comment: What is the special insight which is provided by confirming the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648735/7733418 for a given version? This seems like a comment on that answer. Pleae do not misuse answer posts for commenting.